# Walking Along or Walking On

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I had seen them walking **on/along** the road past my window several times before.

Which should I use: *along* or *on*?

Can I use one in place of other without changing meaning and sense?

Answer (score 2):

*along* refers to moving in a constant direction, whereas *on* doesn't.

Therefore to answer your question, it would depend on the context.  In your example, because you have already referred to a direction of travel by using the phrase "past my window", then these could almost be used synonymously, but there is still a subtle difference in meaning.

Comment: Exactly. Walking *on the road* could mean walking in circles on top of the road. It could mean walking *across the road.* Walking *along the road* means walking roughly parallel to (and possibly, but not necessarily directly on top of) the road. The sidewalk and utility lines run **along** the road, but not **on** it.

Comment: _I had seen them walking on the road instead of the sidewalk._ In a context like that, _on_ is better, but usually _along_ is the better preposition.

Comment: @J.R. - I agree, along is better.